# Visual Studio 2017 Remote Debugging: Network Connection Lost

Tags: visual-studio-2017, remote-debugging

1. Installed Visual Studio Remote Debugger 2017 on Windows Server 2012.
2. Running Visual Studio 2017 on my laptop, I attached my code successfully to a process running on the server SOMESERVER:4022.
3. I run the target process on the server up to where my breakpoint should hit.
4. Visual Studio pushes to the front as if my breakpoint is about to hit.
5. I get "The network connection to SOMESERVER:4023 has been lost. Debugging will be aborted.

Notice that I connect using port 4022 but the connection loss notes 4023. I assume it's because I'm running x86 application on x64 server.

Ideas?